# Unable to upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04 (GUI does not launch, nothing on terminal)

Tags: 20.04, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04 but it did not work. I first ran the [following](https://vitux.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-to-21-04/):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo shutdown -r now
```

after restarting, I still had 20.04.
I tried manually from Software & updates, it shows an upgrade available

[image]

but when I press OK, no other windows show up. On terminal I got:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu focal InRelease      
Hit:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:5 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                        
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease            
Get:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Hit:9 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ InRelease     
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Hit:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease          
Hit:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease              
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu focal InRelease      
Get:14 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]  
Hit:15 http://apt.insync.io/ubuntu focal InRelease                             
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/smathot/cogscinl/ubuntu focal InRelease        
Hit:17 https://linux-clients.seafile.com/seafile-deb/focal stable InRelease    
Hit:8 https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb/releases/download/apt-get ./ InRelease
Fetched 214 kB in 3s (68.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libboost-date-time-dev/focal 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.67.0.2]
libboost-filesystem-dev/focal 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.67.0.2]
libboost-iostreams-dev/focal 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.67.0.2]
libboost-program-options-dev/focal 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.67.0.2]
libboost-system-dev/focal 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.67.0.2]
$ sudo apt upgrade libboost-system-dev/focal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '1.71.0.0ubuntu2' (Ubuntu:20.04/focal [amd64]) for 'libboost-system-dev'
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libboost-system-dev : Depends: libboost-system1.71-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
$ sudo apt upgrade libboost-system-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libboost-system-dev : Depends: libboost-system1.71-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

What could be the problem and how can I solve it? Shall I remove these files that are still pending? What command shall I use?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade? Because you need something, that does not exist or does not work in 20.04.x LTS? Or because it is possible (or should be possible)? The version 20.04.x LTS has long time support for 5 years and is well debugged and polished while 21.04 has a lifetime of only 9 months (until January 2022).

Comment: There is no tested, supported upgrade path from 20.04 to 21.04. There was such a path, via 20.10, but 20.10 is past End of Life so that window is closed. The recommended and supported method is to backup your data and reinstall. There are other methods you can try (like using `dist-upgrade` properly), but those are outside of normal support: Not tested, not supported.

Comment: Well, the answer on `why update` is: because it is possible. I understood the newer version should have better capabilities. But the point is: another machine smoothly started the upgrade process. There is something wrong with the present machine...

Comment: Sometimes, even when a computer works well with one version of Ubuntu, there might be problems with the next version because of problems with the driver for some particular piece of hardware. There are also risks when release-upgrading, that some setting from the old system will not be compatible with the new version of Ubuntu. For that reason a fresh installation is much more likely to succeed [than release-upgrading].

Comment: To fix problems with existing packages try to use Aptitude - `sudo apt-get install aptitude`, `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade` . Please share error output if any. Upgrading to 21.04 is not recommended, you loose LTS support status.

Comment: I think after all it was a problem of hard disk. I changed it and re-installed the whole lot. Thanks